# Launching firefox through putty, and open it up in LXDE desktop

Tags: firefox, vnc, lxde, remote, putty

I am trying to run from local machine firefox on remote server, and don't know how to accomplish that.

I use putty to connect to server and when I type the firefox command, I get `Error: no display specified`

I have LXDE desktop installed on Ubuntu 12.04 and use tightvnc to access server desktop.

What I need to do is launch firefox locally and be able to use firefox in vnc session.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To archieve what you want, you need to enable X11 forwarding when connecting to the remote server.

In addition, to display Firefox (X11 Client), you need a X11 Server running on your LXDE desktop (which is already the case, OS X has X Server, too. Windows may need XMing X Server).

To enable X11 Forwarding, you don't have to use PuTTY, in any Terminal emulator session:

`ssh -X user@remote_server`

> **NOTE**: `ssh -X` will automatically set DISPLAY to => `localhost:10.0`. BTW: Use `-Y` to enable trusted X11 forwarding temporarily.

Once connected, type `firefox` and you'll be able to see the GUI on your LXDE desktop.

If you really want to use PuTTY anyway, in putty configuration -> SSH -> X11, check Enable X11 Forwarding.